# Omnet Execution time / CPU time

Tags: execution-time, omnet++

I am trying to test the CPU (or execution) running time for a simulation in OMNeT++. Is there any parameter or logfile where I can find the execution time after a simulation?

I have found the "CPU-limit-time" parameter so I guess that what I am looking for must exist too, however I have had no luck so far ;)

I would appreciate your help a lot, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No, OMNeT++ does not measure the CPU time or wall clock time spent on the simulation (although it can limit the CPU time). You can measure this with external tools.

Just use the `time` command on the shell and it will start your simulation and will dump out the timing statistics on the standard output when it finishes.

> $ cd samples/aloha
>
> $ time ./aloha -u Cmdenv -c PureAloha1 fingerprints.ini

Answer (score 1):

If you use CMDENV, when the simulation finish, it prints the last event and the elapsed time:

> ** Event #3870352   T=240.2018325552   **Elapsed: 27.090s (0m 27s)**  0% completed
>        Speed:     ev/sec=142870   simsec/sec=8.86681   ev/simsec=16112.9
>        Messages:  created: 1646911   present: 670   in FES: 0
>
> No more events -- simulation ended at event #3870352,
>   t=240.2018325552.

In this example, it has taken 27.090s. If you want, you could write a script for extracting this value.

Comment: I tried this in my code and in the aloha's project as well and I get the below error "Error: Cannot open ini file 'fingerprints.ini'". Any idea how to solve that ?

Answer (score -1):

This is provided by C++:

Define variables to store CPU time:

```
double startCPUclocks;
double endCPUclocks;
```

Run the following when a piece of code starts:

```
    startCPUclocks = clock();
    ... some code here....
    endCPUclocks = clock();
```

Then the cpu time can be computed as:

```
   endCPUclocks - startCPUclocks;
```